# Can a child RenderObject take a parent transformation into account?

Tags: flutter

I have implemented a 'Marker' that uses a GlobalKey to find the location of a Container and draws a blue box around it. This works great as long as no transformation is taking place (e.g. FittedBox with scaleDown). But if there is, the blue box appears at an incorrect position.

Does anyone know how to account for the transformation to make the blue box appear in the correct location?

Full code example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

var boxKey = GlobalKey();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          child: FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
            child: Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              color: Colors.yellow,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  const Marker(),
                  Align(
                      alignment: const Alignment(-0.5, -0.5),
                      child: Container(
                        key: boxKey,
                        width: 30,
                        height: 30,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      )),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Marker extends LeafRenderObjectWidget {
  const Marker({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  RenderMarker createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return RenderMarker();
  }

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(BuildContext context, RenderMarker renderObject) {}
}

class RenderMarker extends RenderProxyBox {
  @override
  void performLayout() {
    super.performLayout();
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    super.paint(context, offset);

    var renderBox = boxKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    var center = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) +
        Offset(renderBox.size.width / 2, renderBox.size.height / 2);

    context.canvas.drawRect(
        Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: 50, height: 50),
        Paint()..color = Colors.blue);
  }
}
```

Comment: make `Marker` as a child of the `Container` - why do you want that `GlobalKey` at all?

Comment: My actual use case is much more complicated. The sample code just illustrates the problem in the simplest way. And I'm wondering if there's even a solution if I do it the GlobalKey way.

Comment: most likely you need `RenderObject.getTransformTo` method, or `CompositedTransformFollower` / `CompositedTransformTarget` - it all depends on what actually you want to achieve, what is your "more complicated" case?

Comment: It is something like a word search game. There is a board with letters and the user can mark words by selecting letters with their finger. I want to draw a line around the selected word. To achieve this I need to know where the letters are rendered. This is why I use the RenderObjects (per GlobalKey).
This works great unless I have a FittedBox around it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution:

```
@override
void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    super.paint(context, offset);

    var renderBox = boxKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;

    var p = parent! as RenderObject;

    var parentOffset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero, ancestor: p);

    var center = parentOffset +
        Offset(renderBox.size.width / 2, renderBox.size.height / 2);

    context.canvas.drawRect(
        Rect.fromCenter(center: center + offset, width: 50, height: 50),
        Paint()..color = Colors.blue);
}
```

Notice how I calculate everything in relation to the parent now.